# Why am I getting ' BAD_REQUEST Unprocessable JSON'?

Tags: php, html, json, rest, post

I'm trying to make a call to a REST-API but it only returns 'BAD_REQUEST Unprocessable JSON'.

I've tried rewriting the input as the example I'm following, but it just gives me the same error.

This is the code I'm using for sending the request:

```php
function callAPI($method, $url, $data) 
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    $username = 'PK10008_e8f77aebdb0a';
    $password = 'rwBmthNFK8JTbIL7';

    switch($method)
    {
      case "POST":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         break;
    }

    //Options
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result)
    {
        die("Connection Failure");
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

And this is the code I'm using to create and send the information:

```php
    $data_array = array(
        'purchase_country'=> 'SE',
        'purchase_currency'=> 'SEK',
        'locale'=> 'sv-SE',
        'order_amount'=> 10,
        'order_tax_amount'=> 0,
        'order_lines' => array(
            'type'=> 'physical',
            'reference'=> '19-402',
            'name'=> 'Test',
            'quantity'=> 1,
            'unit_price'=> 10,
            'tax_rate'=> 0,
            'total_amount'=> 10,
            'total_discount_amount'=> 0,
            'total_tax_amount'=> 0
        )
    );

    $make_call = callAPI('POST', 'https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions', json_encode($data_array));
    $response = json_decode($make_call, true);
```

And this is the example:

```
POST /payments/v1/sessions
Authorization: Basic pwhcueUff0MmwLShJiBE9JHA==
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "purchase_country": "SE",
  "purchase_currency": "SEK",
  "locale": "sv-SE",
  "order_amount": 10,
  "order_tax_amount": 0,
  "order_lines": [{
    "type": "physical",
    "reference": "19-402",
    "name": "Battery Power Pack",
    "quantity": 1,
    "unit_price": 10,
    "tax_rate": 0,
    "total_amount": 10,
    "total_discount_amount": 0,
    "total_tax_amount": 0
  }]
}
```

The result I'm getting is this: 
'BAD_REQUEST
Unprocessable JSON
1734c472-c9cb-4022-b469-a8231c7abeec'

But I should be getting some thing like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "session_id": "068df369-13a7-4d47-a564-62f8408bb760",
  "client_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjAwMDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwIiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jcmVkaXQtZXUua2xhcm5hLmNvbSJ9.A_rHWMSXQN2NRNGYTREBTkGwYwtm-sulkSDMvlJL87M",
  "payment_method_categories": [{
      "identifier": "pay_later"
      "name" : "Pay later.",
      "asset_urls" : {
        "descriptive" : "https://cdn.klarna.com/1.0/shared/image/generic/badge/en_us/pay_later/descriptive/pink.svg",
        "standard" : "https://cdn.klarna.com/1.0/shared/image/generic/badge/en_us/pay_later/standard/pink.svg"
      }
  }]
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read [the parameter description of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS on the manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: But isn't the data being sent as a string because of json_encode?

Comment: Yes but the manual says use an assoc array or a `'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' `

Comment: How would I include an array in that format?

Comment: You could try changeing this line `$make_call = callAPI('POST', 'https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions', json_encode($data_array))` to pass `$data_array` without json_encoding it

Comment: That gave me this error: Array to string conversion here: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I was having was how json_encode creates encodes arrays. Instead of this: `"example":[{
   "ex": "ex"
}]`

It did this:
`"example":{
   "ex": "ex"
}`

Which in turn made the json unreadable to the end API